# How to book Busan/Korea to Osaka/Japan ferry

Tags: bookings, south-korea, ferries

There is a ferry operator Panstar that runs a ferry from Busan to Osaka. The [JP site](http://www.panstar.jp/) of the company offers the [online booking](http://www.panstar.jp/webreserve/) but it looks the company does not offer a online booking from Busan to Osaka. directferries.com offers a way but the reputation seems not good as I saw complaints of not getting refund.

Please advise if there is a way.

Comment: I think it's here. You need to purchase from the Korean website: https://www.panstarcruise.com/main/contents.html

Comment: @mkennedy, thanks a lot!